# How to find start/end cluster for a file

Tags: hard-drive

In O&O defrag, after doing analysiz, we can see what file in each cluster. What if I am looking for a certain file, is there any tool to know in which cluster that file are? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: I suspect that file overwrite some of my old files. I was to locate it in O&O and find adjacent files.

Comment: What if the file is fragmented?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I determine what file occupies a given sector?](http://superuser.com/questions/97823/how-do-i-determine-what-file-occupies-a-given-sector)