# How do I determine what file occupies a given sector in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, bad-sectors

In Linux, I'd like to know how to find the file(s) if any which as using a particular sector on the hard drive (ext2/3). There is a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/97823/how-do-i-determine-what-file-occupies-a-given-sector) regarding Windows, however I need a Linux command line solution (this is a headless system).

Comment: similar question: http://serverfault.com/questions/315700/how-to-determine-which-file-inode-occupies-a-given-sector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that you need to use [`debugfs`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man8/debugfs.8.php). The long answer, found [here](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/BadBlockHowto), is that first you have to map the disk location to the filesystem location. By the way, you didn't say if your filesystem is ext2/3 or something else. The link is for ext2/3.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. The filesystem is ext3 (I updated my original question).