# How do I determine what file occupies a given sector in Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, filesystems, bad-sectors, hfs+

There are similar questions for [Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/97823/how-do-i-determine-what-file-occupies-a-given-sector) and [Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/130912/how-do-i-determine-what-file-occupies-a-given-sector-in-linux), but I need this on OS X. The filesystem is HFS+, journaled. I have a sector LBA, I could find where a partition starts with `gpt` (though it refuses to work for mounted volumes), but I need something to map a sectors number within an HFS+ volume to the file that contains it.

Edit: I copied the sectors around that area from `/dev/rdisk0` using `dd`, and the contents appear to be parts of the directory structure of the volume. The strange thing is that these were supposed to be damaged sectors, yet they can be read without problems, and `smartctl` reports `Reallocated_Event_Count = 0` and `Current_Pending_Sector = 0`, so they shouldn't have been reallocated...

Answer (score 0):

I see this isn't exactly a recent question / comment ... but I'd love to know how you localized the sectors a file used without scanning it in R-Studio or the likes.

Sure there's a catalog, but, that HFS catalog is nothing like the MFT.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).