# How to find out which files are stored in a certain section on the disk

Tags: windows-7, ntfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I determine what file occupies a given sector?](https://superuser.com/questions/97823/how-do-i-determine-what-file-occupies-a-given-sector)

My hard drive recently spit out bad sectors. I used ddrescue to clone it onto a another drive. Unfortunately there were a few hundred bad sectors it could not copy. They are located between 9 - 11.5GB into the C partition. Windows starts up fine and I have no trouble working with it so far so it seems no critical system files were corrupted. However I'd like to find out which file are located in that area so I get an idea of which files could possibly have been corrupted.

Is there any tool around which can show me where the files are physically stored on the disk and lets me compile a list (maybe even a Windows 7 built in tool)? Asking Google for it didn't result in anything useful.

**Edit** to clarify:
I already have a new drive (same model) and I cloned the old drive sector by sector. I'd just like to know which files might have been affected by the bad sectors. As stated in my comment the SMART data indicates that no sectors have been reallocated yet as they have not been written to.

As far as CHKDSK is concerned the filesystem on the new drive is happy, so the bad sectors did not affect any meta data.