# How to find out what file is on a particular sector

Tags: linux, software-rec, ntfs, data-recovery

How do i find out on Linux what file is occupying a given sector on a NTFS partition? I need to do it because i am rescuing data from a failing HDD (using `ddrescue`), and want to find out what files have been corrupted by bad sectors.

Comment: Not an answer, but still good related info: [NTFS file recovery techniques](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42450/advanced-ntfs-partition-file-recovery-techniques-for-damaged-drives-io-errors).

Comment: Never used it myself, but [ntfscluster](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfscluster) looks encouraging.  Some of the other ntfsprogs look interesting as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that the needed utility was mentioned right on the Ubuntu Rescue Remix (Ubuntu Rescue Remix was discontinued in 2012) front page: ddrutility

Homepage of `ddrutility`: https://sourceforge.net/projects/ddrutility/

Answer (score 4):

The comment provided by rickhg12hs deserves a place as an answer - it's on the mark.

The ntfs-3g utilities provide some useful functionality.  In my experience, the **ntfscluster** tool has an advantage over **ddrutility** in that it can stand alone, whereas **ddru_ntfsfindbad** requires a **ddrescue** logfile.  Not a problem in the context of the OP - as long as the logfile is still available.

Try something like:

```
 ntfscluster -s 1048576 /dev/sda2
```

to identify what file occupies *partition* sector 1048576 of the NTFS partition /dev/sda2.  If the drive has errors, you can try including the `-f` option, but weigh the results accordingly.

Because even the `-q` option for quiet output can be a bit chatty, consider redirecting **stderr** to /dev/null using `2>/dev/null` so that only only the file details output to **stdout** are displayed.

Comment: I presume a sector here is 512 bytes?  If so, I guess I can calculate the appropriate partition sector with something like `$(( (ddrescue_byte_offset/512) - partition_start_sector ))`?