# How to view where the data are actually placed in an hdd's platter(s)

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, visualization, data-visualization

I have found some programs, but they just display the hierarchy of the files/folders in a sunburst chart.
What I want is to view the data as they are actually placed/scatered in sectors/tracks of the platter. 
Is tere any way to do it?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/97823/how-do-i-determine-what-file-occupies-a-given-sector

Comment: Not like this, a disk chart with the data placed onto.

Comment: As you pointed out, DiskView from Sysinternals does it, althought is a bit crumbersome. Post is as answer to close this question

Answer (score 0):

The olny software I have used untill now that will somehow show if the files are placed near the edge ("high performance" files) or near the center ("slow performance" or "archive" files) on the platter is Ultimate Defrag.