# How to change the start point of a partition with a bad sector

Tags: partitioning, windows-10

I hope I am asking on the right site, if not please guide me to the correct site.

I have a 300GB hard drive. It has a bad sector where my C drive is.

I have free space on its left but when I right-click, it grays out the extend partition button. In GParted, the same happens and warns me there is a bad sector.
Please help me to move the start point of my C drive

Comment: You should not be messing around with this for the sake of a new hdd or ssd. Bad sectors dont get better and the hard disk is way past its use-by date.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than messing with partitions of a "live" system, you can try using [`sdelete -z C:`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sdelete)

If the bad sector is on free space (ie: in unused disk portion and not containing useful data), the above command will force a bad block reallocation.

If the bad sector affect an in-use sector (ie: one containing valuable data), you need to accept data loss. Than you have two possibilities:

- wait for a rewrite of the affected sector (and the relative reallocation done by disk firmware);
- force a reallocation, manually zeroing the affected sector (in this case, I strongly suggest you to read [that superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/97823/how-do-i-determine-what-file-occupies-a-given-sector)).

Comment: Please explain to me the meaning of your first line and the 2 points for a fix when bad sector affects an in-use sector. I am going to read the link after writing this comment